# Spam Analysis Tool

Tags: spam

I looked but did not see a question related specifically at spam analysis tools. What I want to do is run our auto generated notification emails through some tools to determine their spam likelihood rating.

Comment: Do you look for spam that have been accepted by the MTA (and hopefully recognized by the spam filter) or are you also interrested by SMTP rejections (that are for many of them related to spam) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the spam assassin score is always a good test.  [This tool](http://www.mailingcheck.com/download-spam-checker/) gives you a spam assassin rating on windows, without having to install spam assassin.

You might also want to look a list of the [spam assassin tests](http://spamassassin.apache.org/tests_3_2_x.html)

I hope your not a spammer.  If i start getting more viagra emails, I'll know it was you!

Comment: i know, this type of question can be used for good or bad, but I promise it is just used for notification emails that people have specificly requested. Click here for free cialis.....

Answer (score 0):

Try this [Online Email Server Test](http://www.allaboutspam.com/email-server-test)